# groupby pandas with a list on each record?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that is consist of 3 columns

```
df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":[11199,123244,11287,32345,12342,1232,11287,123244,13456],
             "name":["roky anderson ","james jacob","suzan kor","jenny mayor","joseph owin","joe kabush","georges mathiu","kobby lon","adam wein"],
             "category":["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })
```

I want to perform a Group By function on **category** and **source number**

The Result :

```
source_number   category     name   
1232             cat3      {joe kabush}
11199            cat1      {roky anderson}
11287            cat2      {suzan cor - georges mathius}
12342            cat1      {joseph owin}
13456            cat3      {adam wein}
32345            cat3      {jenny mayor}
123244           cat2      {james jacob - kobby lon}
```

**what I want is to split the **name** values where it contains more that 1 value  either into a new column or new row.**

Expected output:

```
source_number   category     name            name2
1232             cat3      {joe kabush}       nan
11199            cat1      {roky anderson}    nan
11287            cat2      {suzan cor }     {georges mathius}
12342            cat1      {joseph owin}       nan
13456            cat3      {adam wein}         nan
32345            cat3      {jenny mayor}       nan
123244           cat2      {james jacob}    {kobby lon}
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd 

my_dict{
                "source_number":[11199,123244,11287,32345,12342,1232,11287,123244,13456],
                 "name":["roky anderson ","james jacob","suzan kor","jenny mayor","joseph owin","joe kabush","georges mathiu","kobby lon","adam wein"],
                 "category":["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
                 }
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

df_group = df.groupby(["source_number","category"])["name"].apply(lambda x: "{%s}" %' - '.join(x)).to_frame()
```

Comment: can you please post your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATED ANSWER`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["source_number"], as_index=False).agg({'name' : list, 'category' : 'last'})
result = pd.concat([df1[['source_number','category']] ,
           pd.concat([df1['name'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('name' + "_")], axis=1)],
          axis = 1)
result = result.filter(like='name').applymap(lambda x:"{%s}" %x)
```

`NOTE:` Format the name column later if required.

Comment: i did tried your answer but it did not return the excepted result

Comment: also did not return the expected answer instead it the `dict` into `list` and replace the `-` with `,`

Comment: @user5980666 try now added formatting please use your initial dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is stored in a variable `df_group` then(If Its your Initial dataframe):

Try with `split()`:

```
df_group['name2']='{'+df_group['name'].str.split('-',expand=True)[1].str.rstrip('}')+'}'
df_group['name']='{'+df_group['name'].str.split('-',expand=True)[0].str.strip('{}')+'}'
```

Now If you print `df_group` you will get your desired output:

```
source_number   category     name            name2
1232             cat3      {joe kabush}       nan
11199            cat1      {roky anderson}    nan
11287            cat2      {suzan cor }     {georges mathius}
12342            cat1      {joseph owin}       nan
13456            cat3      {adam wein}         nan
32345            cat3      {jenny mayor}       nan
123244           cat2      {james jacob}    {kobby lon}
```

### Update:

Try with `split()` and `apply()` method:

```
result=df_group['name'].str.split('-',expand=True)
result=result.apply(lambda x:'{'+x.str.strip('{}')+'}',1)
df_group[['name'+str(x+1) for x in result.columns]]=result
```

Now If you print `df_group` you will get your desired output

Comment: Bro, that's not what he asked for. He provided the initial df, and the table shows the expected output. If I'm not wrong.

Comment: ohh...I think that the result is initial dataframe and OP want the expected output from that result

Comment: Well he edited the question again. So, i was wrong.

Comment: @AnuragDabas what if i had more than 2 items in the dictionary ??means if i want to split the items in columns based on the length of the dict ??

Comment: Updated answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: ok i will try it , but what if i have some records with 2 items and others with 4 or 6 items  isn't more efficient to iterate over the `dict` ??
how to perform this iteration ?

Comment: i tried your answer and it crash and display  :
`valueError: 3 is not in range `

Comment: It means you have not more than 2 values present in the name column of each row

Comment: no i added a value for a row  so the `name column` in the  `df_group`  will have on 1 record  a dict with 3 items like this :`{suzan cor- georges mathius - kobby lon }`

Comment: so what do you want to do with `{suzan cor- georges mathius - kobby lon }`? I mean did you want to convert it to 2 columns or to 3 columns?...if you convert it into 2 columns it will look like  `{suzan cor}      {georges mathius - kobby lon }` and if you want to convert it in 3 columns then it will look like  `{suzan cor}      {georges mathius }        {kobby lon }`

Comment: i want to split it into 3 columns because the dict has 3 items  so if it has 4 or 6 i want it to split into  4 or 6 columns

Comment: sorry for the late reply but it didn't work

Comment: its woking on my side